# Jenkins build is not timing out even when Build Timeout is explicitly mentioned

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've mentioned build timeout in jenkins job as per attached screen shot[image]

But even with this setting build is not timing out even after 2 -4 hrs.

I use jenkins job to do GET requests to REST end points.
There is a bug with one of the end point which results in response not being sent in required time.

Please clarify how to get time out fixed with jenkins job ?

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Abort the build if it's stuck" option is offered by the "Build Timeout Plugin".

According to [the documentation of the "Build Timeout Plugin" (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) :

> [...] depending on how a build hangs, the abort operation might not take effect.

The documentation lists a couple of possible reasons.  Make sure you are not affected by one of those reasons.  (I cannot tell without seeing a lot more of your configuration and precisely how you place those GET requests.)

Comment: Is there any other plugin which does hard stop on jenkins job ? The problem I'm facing RESTful api call take infinite time to respond back, I would like to terminate after X minutes.

Comment: I do not know of any other plugin, but then again I am not terribly familiar with all the plugins that exist out there for jenkins.  However, you might have better luck by finding a way to prevent your http request from waiting for a response forever.  There must be an option somewhere to set a very shot timeout.  If not, then whatever library you are using for your http requests is lame, and I would suggest replacing it with a different one.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your inputs, will debug further